# textfield text appears at the top of the box in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

hi i have made a simple css class and i have increased the height of the text box .
the problem is that the text starts near the top in IE7 (as if i have not changed the height).
but in Firefox the text appears vertically aligned.
now my question is that how can i make the text in the vertical middle of the box in internet explorer 
here is my css

```
.textfield{
    height:40px;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#999;
}
```

and this is my html

```
<input name="" type="text" value="" class="textfield">
```

Comment: Such a tall text box! Padding might be better than height... Remember to give the box a name as well ;)

Comment: thank for the help .. :) yeah sure but this is just a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have IE7, so I can't test this out, but my suggestion is that you can try to use padding instead of setting an actual height. That way I believe you will get the equal amount of spacing above and below the text, thus causing the text to look vertically aligned.

```
.textfield{
    padding:10px 0;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#999;
}
```

Of course you will have to experiment with the amount of padding to use, I put `10px` in as an example.

Comment: well i think that i should start using my mind instead of just pulling my hair huh..? really thank you for the help